# Prove or Disprove the Conjecture on Cousin Primes

Tags: prime-numbers, permutations, conjectures

Here is the problem in a nutshell -

**Ethers or Ether of n, $\mathbf{\eth(n)}$:** Ethers of any number n is the set of all the values of every possible permutations of its digits.

Illustration Ethers of $123$, $\eth(123)$= $123, 132, 213, 231, 312$ and $321$. Similarly it follows that $\eth(123)=\eth(132)=\eth(213)=\eth(231)=\eth(312)=\eth(321)$

**Magnitude of Ether n, denoted by $|\eth(n)|$** is the total count of Prime Numbers we obtain by considering all of its Ethers individually.

Illustration $|\eth(38)|=\mid\eth(83)|=1$,
$|\eth(67)|=1$, $|\eth(251)|=2$, $|\eth(157)|=3$, $|\eth(973)|=4$, $|\eth(2183)|=6$, $|\eth(1379)|=7$, $|\eth(7309)|=9$, $|\eth(5917)|=10$, $|\eth(1237)|=11$ and so on…

---

**Zeroes of Ether** Any natural number $n$ such that $| \eth(n)|= 0$ is termed as zeroes of Ether, and if such $n$ can be explained, trivially, then it's termed as **Trivial Zeroes of Ether**.

Trivial Zeroes of Ether are classified as follows

1.) All the multiples of $3$, $| \eth(3m)| = 0$, $m \in{W}$
2.) The number having any of these digits $(0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8)$ in any combinations.
3.) Any number $(>11)$ entirely made up of only a single digit $(>1)$.
4.) All the numbers of form $k \cdot 10^\alpha$, $\mathit{| \eth(k\cdot 10^\alpha)| =0, \, 0 \leq k \leq 9, \, \alpha\in{W}}$

---

**CONJECTURE 1** If $P_{n+1} - P_n =2$ then there always exists $k$ such that $| \eth(k)| = 0$ for $P_n < k < P_{n+1}$.

**CONJECTURE 2** If $P_{n+1} - P_n = 4$ then there exists minimum one $k$ such that $| \eth(k)| \geq 1$ for $P_n < k < P_{n+1}$ where all of its Exceptions are Trivial Zeroes of Ether.

---

It's just a segment from my original post  [On The Distribution of Prime Numbers](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1988003p13840392)
I tried my best to handle this Conjecture 2 but couldn't get anywhere. I thought the representation of Primes in base $10$ would incinerate this problem but no progress was made.
Any progress will be highly appreciated.

*Remark* \eth symbol is being utilitized for the new notions of digit permutations.

Edit: Rephrased the Conjecture for better clarification.

Comment: We do not even know whether there are infinite many prime pairs of the form $(p,p+4)$

Comment: `\mid` is a binary operator (e.g. for divisibility or for conditional probabilities). Don't use it instead of `|` for norm bars; as you can see, that messes up the spacing.

Comment: @Peter it's valid till the prime gap length of 4 exists, this is the Conjecture.

Comment: Cross-posted on MO at [Conjecture on the Distribution of Primes generated from the Permutations of numbers between Cousin Primes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/350743/129887).

Answer (score 0):

> CONJECTURE 1: If $P_{n+1}−P_{n}=2$ then there always exists $k$ such that $|\eth(k)|=0$ for $P_n<k<P_{n+1}$

$$$$

> (smacks forehead audibly) How could we have missed this !  Oh right ... **only one such $k$ exists between them ever**  It's also a multiple of 3 in all but one instance, making it a trivial case **by your definition** .

$$$$

> CONJECTURE 2 If $P_{n+1}−P_n=4$ then there exists minimum one $k$ such that $|\eth(k)|\geq 1$ for $P_n<k<P_{n+1}$ where all of its Exceptions are Trivial Zeroes of Ether.

Well it can't be their average that's a multiple of 3.  A number can only be 2 mod 6, if it contains:

- at least 1 even digit, and the number of 1 mod 3 and digits out numbers the 2 mod 3 digits by a 2 mod 3 amount
- the number of 2 mod 3 digits out number the number of 1 mod 3 digits by a 1 mod 3 amount.

It immediately follows that if the first case is true the number taking off the odd last digit ( 1 or 7 digits rearrangement case) we need it to be 1 mod 3 .

Both cases fail if the digit put last  is 2 mod 3 because 5 is the only odd digit that it could be, so it falls to it's companions in 1 or 0 mod 3.

In the case of ending in 0 mod 3, the last digit removal must give 2 mod  3 because if not it isn't in the same equivalence class.

Similar constraints ( though inverted) can be put on in the 4 mod 6 case.

It's still unclear how you can guarantee at least 1.

Comment: I guarantee at least 1 because... Of the Non Trivial Zeroes of Ether

Comment: Please have a look at these specific cousin prime pairs - (673,677) , ,(739,743) , (769,773) , (967,971) there are many such. I hope your arguments could explain their behavior

Comment: last one has 97 a prime ( lost a leading 0), 277 for the second last, 47 for the third last, 647 for the first.

Comment: 647, 467, 047, 277, 097, 079, 709, 907 are all primes

Comment: You still haven't given proof that we should care.16588789876554675462233 should at least keep you quiet ...

Comment: what do you mean by keep quite and what's specific about that number here?!

Comment: it'll keep you busy so you can think about the problem more ... it's part of a cousin prime pair, if your conjecture is universal it should work on arbitrary sizes...

Comment: what has happened to you suddenly?! I didn't imagined that you'll give any random cousin prime and ask for Conjecture true like that. I've limited computational capacity. You're missing the main point. The numbers 676, 742, 968 ... No matter how much you permute they won't give prime ever, that's the thing I emphasized upon by listing those cousin prime pairs and primes which we got from the permutations.

Comment: I Also have limited computational capacity, try PARI GP online version ...

Comment: please tell me what's happening to the Conjecture with that number. I'm curious and nervous.

Comment: My point is you need to try all size of number, it may not hold indefinitely. if all odd digits are 5, it will never work for that number not to be a zero for example.

Comment: should I add or subtract from that number to get the other prime among cousin primes?! Yup I take care of your concerns

Comment: wait what?! If all digits are 5?! That is what the Conjecture says, Exceptions are trivial zeroes of ether!

Comment: `forprime(x=1,1000,if(isprime(x+4),parapply(r->forperm(y=digits(r),s,if(isprime(fromdigits(Vec(s),10)),print(x"+"r-x" gives a prime"))),[x+1,x+2,x+3])))`

Comment: all 0's can be explained in theory ... you've literally forced the conjecture...

Comment: yup it's true, theoretically all Zeroes can be explained, but it happened with trivial zeroes only. I still found it difficult to explain the Non Trivial Zeroes of Ether

Comment: such as ... 12.5+% of cousin pairs with lower term under 1 million fail to have a rearrangement of the digits of relevant numbers in between that create primes.

Comment: thanks a lot for the data.

Comment: I request you to visit this link. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1988003p13840392